# Inequality proof by induction of $n!>2^n+3^n$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction, proof-explanation

Give a proof by induction: 
$\forall n\ge n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $n!>2^n+3^n$.

Attempt:

Base case: $n_0=7$

Induction step:

$k!>2^k+3^k$

Prove $(k+1)!>3^{k+1}+2^{k+1}$

We know $(k+1)!>(k+1)(2^k+3^k)$

as $(k+1)>6 \because k\ge 7$:

$(k+1)!>6(2^k+3^k)$

$(k+1)!>3*2^{k+1}+2*3^{k+1}$

as $3*2^{k+1}+2*3^{k+1}>3*2^{k+1}+2*3^{k+1}-2*2^{k+1}-3^{k+1}$

$(k+1)!>2^{k+1}+3^{k+1}$

still getting my head around this method of induction with inequalities.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's a good work! Just note that for induction step it suffices to assume $k>2$ and since the base case is for $k=7$ it's ok. If we had found an induction step true for $k>10$ then we had to go back to prove the base case for $k=11$ in order to complete the proof.

Comment: Of course I suppose you mean to refer to "inequalities".

Comment: Gotcha, so my induction is correct just not as "rigorous" as yours so to speak? Thank you very much! And yes I mean inequalities.

Comment: @RJM In your solution I find not so clear the step $(k+1)!>6(2^k+3^k)\implies (k+1)!>3*2^{k+1}+2*3^{k+1}$, as noted in my anser we can directly conclude since $(k+1)!>6(2^k+3^k)>2^{k+1}+3^{k+1}$.

Answer (score 4):

From here for $k> 2$ we have

$$(k+1)!\stackrel{I.H.}>(k+1)(2^k+3^k)=(k+1)2^k+(k+1)3^k>2\cdot 2^k+3\cdot 3^k=2^{k+1}+3^{k+1}$$

and this prove the induction step.